# Do I really need to use touchstart or just click do the job?

Tags: jquery, touchstart

I have something like this in my jquery scripts:

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".button", function() {
```

it appears to work fine in all touch devices too, I haven't notice any issue in my test. Do I really need to add touchstart? Like this:

```
$( document ).on( "click touchstart", ".button", function() {
```

Or it is irrelevant nowadays?

Comment: So I use touchstart just to click on iphone working faster?

Comment: It depends on how you want your UI to work. If you want the user to have to press and release, use `click`. If you want to perform the action as soon as the touch is made, use `touchstart`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you very much friend